# How to find $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such as $2z + i\bar{z} = 4$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm currently doing some exercices about Complex numbers and I've been trying to resolve this kind of equations but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried unsuccessfully to replace $z$ by $x+yi$ and $\bar{z}$ by $x-yi$.

I really have no idea what I should do to get rid of $\bar{z}$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: conjugate $2z + i\bar{z} = 4$ to get $2 \bar z - iz = 4\,$, then eliminate $\bar z$ between the two equations.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method with **manipulation on z**:

$$2z + i\bar{z} = 4 \implies 2\bar{z} - iz = 4 $$

$$2z + i\bar{z} = 4 \implies i(2z + i\bar{z}) = i(4) \implies 2iz -\bar{z} = 4i\implies 4iz -2\bar{z} = 8i$$

thus:

$$2\bar{z} - iz = 4, \quad 4iz -2\bar{z} = 8i\implies 3iz= 4+8i \implies 3iz= -4i+8 $$

that is:

$$z= \frac83-\frac43i$$

Answer (score 3):

A way not involving $z=x+iy$ is to take the conjugate of your equation to have a system of two

$$\begin{cases}2z+i\bar{z}=4\\2\bar{z}-iz=4\end{cases}$$

Now multiply the first equation by $2$, the second by $i$ and subtract to have

$$2\left(2z+i\bar{z}\right)-i\left(2\bar{z}-iz\right)=2\cdot4-i\cdot4$$

$$3z=8-4i$$

and finally

$$z=\frac{8}{3}-\frac{4}{3}i$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $z = x+iy$, then
$$2z+i\overline{z} = 2x+2iy + i(x-iy) = 2x+2iy + ix + y.$$
Can you simplify, set that equal to $4$, and continue from there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roger, I tried this, then I factored $x$ and $y$ so I can get $x(2+i)+y(2i+1)$ which looks wrong, because the real part and the imaginary part are supposed to be real numbers rights ?

Comment: Group them differently. You want the real part to be equal to $4$, and the imaginary part to $0$. What is the real part of $2x+2iy+ix+y$?

Comment: Oh I see, so this is equal to $(2x+y)+i(x+2y)$ where $2x+y = 4$ and $x+2y=0$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help !